# Should a red blood cell in hypertonic solution be drawn with a nucleus or not?

Tags: cell-biology

I'm a student at 6th stage in High school from Iraq. I need to draw a red blood cell when it is put in a hypertonic solution; *"high concentration of solute and low concentration of solvent"*.

Do I draw it with a nucleus or not? I think there is no nucleus because the cell has a nucleus only when it is in the bone marrow, but it loses its nucleus later. So when it is put in a hypertonic solution that means it doesn't have nucleus. But my teacher said that it should have a nucleus.

Comment: Hello @handsomecat !! Welcome to Biology SE. Yes! you're right. A mature RBC doesn't have a nucleus. However, for this particular activity, the source of the blood sample has to been taken into consideration. If the sample was taken from a vein, the RBC should be enucleated. If the sample was taken from Bone marrow (generally Hip bone) then RBCs should be nucleated.

Comment: What species?  Human RBC don't have nuclei but some species' (for instance, birds) RBCs do.  May be the source of confusion.

Comment: The nucleus being absent is secondary to what happens with the cell when you put it in a hypertonic solution.  Perhaps you are studying osmosis?

Comment: Yes, it's the osmosis..thank you all.